# How can I access the contents of an Event fired when running in the TFS Server Context?

Tags: c#, delegates, event-handling

I've created a custom event handler for TFS 2012 that fires an event every time a "Work Item" changes. I've followed various examples and found the following code to work on TFS 2012:

```
public class WorkItemChangedEventHandler : ISubscriber
   {
        public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
          {
             return new[] { typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent) };
          }
          public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs,
                                                      out int statusCode, out string statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)
          {
             statusCode = 0;
             properties = null;
             statusMessage = String.Empty;
             try
             {
                if( notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent )
                {
                   var ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
                   EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", "WorkItem " + ev.WorkItemTitle + " was modified");
                }
             }
             catch( Exception exception )
             {
                //must eat all exceptions or TFS will not load the plugin
             }
             return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
          }
          public string Name
          {
             get { return "WorkItemChangedEventHandler"; }
          }
          public SubscriberPriority Priority
          {
             get { return SubscriberPriority.Normal; }
          }
       }
```

SO, while this code runs fine when installed as a .dll in the /plugins directory in TFS, I still don't get how I can get the results from the Event from within external code.

I guess there is some kind of Subscription available through the TFS Server API that lets me subscribe to the events running under the TFS context using a custom event handler (subscriber), but I've tried for a week without luck, so now I'm begging for mercy from the SO community.

What I have is a service that that connects to our Help Desk API and reads Bug Tickets, then I convert this into a serialized local List structure to read from later when I want to check if anything has changed. I then use the TFS API to update the corresponding Work Items, so that everything is in sync.

Everything works on this part of the application, but the problem is that I also need the changes made on TFS (by us developers) to be reflected to the Help Desk Bug tracker. 
So I thought that using a WorkItemChanged() event to do this would spare me the manual coding like I did on the other side.

I need to know what fields on the Work Item changed to update the BugTracker with the new value.

Does anybody have a clue as of how to achieve this?
**The question really boils down to:**
How do I subscribe to the events fired by the above written code from a console or service application?

Help is appreciated.

Chris

Comment: Use the NotificationEventArgs.

Answer (score 1):

You sound like you are not looking for Server side events but rather looking for SOAP events where TFS will call a URL and send a SOAP envelope with the data that you want.

You can just create a web service and get TFS to call it whenever an event of a particular type occurs:

- [Handling Team Foundation Server Events](http://blog.hinshelwood.com/tfs-event-handler-in-net-3-5-part-2-handling-team-foundation-server-events/)

However if you are unable to connect from the TFS server to your console application (usually happens with the local app running on your computer rather than on a server) you can create your own message queue that uses a Duplex service.

To do that you would "host" your own web service end point within the event handler code above and have your clients connect to that. I can see many issues with this that you might run into, but if you don't want to poll and you cant get TFS to fire a soap even on your local box then you would have little choice.

Comment: Ok, thanks! I'll try once more on monday. If I can't get it to work, I'll write my own method to compare server values with local values, like I did on the Help Desk side.